# Player's guns not making noise?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

For the past week or so, every time a specific user enters my game, he shoots me without any noise coming out of the weapon that he uses. Is this a certain type of hack, or do I have an unfortunate coincidence of lag? My ping is 14ms, so I'm pretty sure it's not lag. Should I flag for hacking, or should I just let it go?

Comment: Public/private server? Is he an Admin?

Comment: Its a public server, he is not an admin no

Comment: FYI: the ping (latency) isn't connected to having "lags". "lags" in videogames can have many origins. most of the times it's the server causing them by being overloaded (not enough CPU power or too many connections/requests).  
another popular reason why online-games are lagging are packet losses which aren't connected to your ping either. e.g. you can have a ping of 5ms to a server but losing half of the packets so you are still "lagging" like hell.

Comment: Can you enable your net graph (net_graph 1) and tell us the values that are set within LOSS, CHOKE, SV and VAR please?

There are a few possibilities. Either the server is facing some major issues, or you are facing some major connections issues to the server. This could all happen while your ms (ping) is low.

Comment: If it's not on a Valve server, it's probably just a custom mod on the server, especially if it's consistent with this player and not others.

Comment: let it go let it go

Comment: I find when my ping is high I do not hear gunshots that lead to my death. This is a pain in the ass at times, as AWPs, Deagles, AKs, Scouts and the like, can all do this in one hit and the one hit kill is silent for me. All I hear is the DINK from the headshot - even if the awp was at point blank. However additional shots are heard for me, and shots that miss are too.

Answer (score 1):

I think the guy probably have high ping and many lost packets. Also It can be a server fault (but if its Steam official it will probably not be), or you just have many lost packets, or ingame error - for me few times some textures and sounds dont work, but restarting game fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your steam library, right click on CS:GO and click verify game cache. This is most definitely an error to do with your textures and resources and a sound file or something missing.